# Virtualbox has a different byte code for backspace than an actual bare metal OS

Tags: c, terminal, termios

I'm playing around with non-canonical terminal emulation and trying to compare a single character (my input) to backspace

```
if(c == '\x08')
{
 dosomething();
}
```

works on a bare metal OS but when I run it in virtualbox it doesn't work at all. Virtualbox will only detect a backspace if I do

```
if(c == '\x7f')
{
 dosomething();
}
```

Could this be from the emulation virtualbox is doing interfering with actual keyboard input?

Answer (score 1):

You have just encountered the classic `DEL` vs. `BKSP` dilemma. There is no perfect solution, you have to acknowledge that some terminals are configured to output a `BKSP` (0x08) ASCII character when the user presses backspace, while others output `DEL` (0x7f).

Most terminal emulators have an option for this sort of thing, I have not seen a lot of application software that actually works around this issue. It is usually left up to the terminal program, and the user decides whether to press DEL or BKSP or re-configure their terminal in order to ensure proper program operation.